# How to Find the Latest Open Source Deepfake Detection in Python with High Accuracy?

Tags: deep-fake

I've been searching extensively for the most up-to-date open-source deepfake detection library in Python, but I seem to be hitting a dead end. Everything I've found so far appears to be outdated, and I'm looking for a solution with the highest accuracy available.

I already searched on GitHub and chose the project with the highest rating, but unfortunately, the accuracy did not meet my expectations. Moreover, I noticed that the top-ranking deepfake detection projects on GitHub are all quite old, and I strongly believe that this subject should be kept up-to-date with the latest advancements in deepfake technology.

Could someone please point me in the right direction or recommend the latest and most accurate deepfake detection library or framework in Python that is actively maintained and updated? I want to ensure that I'm using the most current technology to detect deepfakes effectively.

Thank you in advance for your help!

I've even run some of the top-ranked projects referenced on this page https://github.com/topics/deepfake-detection, but unfortunately, the accuracy was lower than desired. Additionally, many of the projects I've come across seem to be quite old.